# Accessing Tumblr variable in JavaScript (convert to string)

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr

I am trying to access a Tumblr variable via JavaScript.

I have created the following option in my theme:

```
<meta name="text:Email" content=""/>
```

This is now showing in the LHS panel in the theme options.

[image].

In my JavaScript/jQuery I have the following variable:

```
var email = $('meta[name="text:Email"]').prop('content');
```

I thought this would return whatever email has been entered into to LHS panel by the client.

However it is only ever returning an empty string. Which is also showing as `content=""` from the meta tag.

Is it the case that these values get written back to the template?

I did try this and it seemed to work:

```
<p class="hidden email">{text:Email}</p>
```

And then the following JavaScript:

```
var email = $('.email').text();
```

returns `"hello@testemail.com"` as a string.

When I tried to run this variable straight in the JavaScript like so:

```
var email = {text:Email};
```

the source JavaScript shows like this:

```
var email = hello@testemail.com; // not a string!
```

I did try a couple of string conversions on the variable but could not get anything to work. However I just want to be able to access the meta property `content=""`. Is there some lag in this data being written back to the template?

Comment: Have you tried `var email = "{text:Email}";`?

Comment: Hahah, it works! That's so weird. I tried concatenation `'"' +{text:Email}+ '"'; ` and `email = email.toString();` neither of which worked. But this worked! I assumed the js would read the curly braces as a string once inside the quote marks. If you want to add it as an answer feel free and I will vote on it.

Comment: If you use `var email = {text:JSEmail};` (with the "JS" prefix) then it will be output with quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Tumblr has a few [variable transformations](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#variable-transformations) and one of which outputs variables to JavaScript strings.

> Prefix any theme variable with JS to output a Javascript string (wrapped in quotes).

Eg: `{text:JSEmail}`